# Privilege for editing tags is at 500 rep but I already have done it before!

Tags: discussion, badges, privileges

When I go to privileges, I see that at 500 reputation I will get the privilege to edit tags to questions.

But the strange thing is that I have already edited tags before.

It also says that I will get an organizer badge on editing a tag first time! And I already have it!

So what is all this? 500 rep needed to earn the edit tags privilege but I already have edited tags before without having that privilege.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before you reach 500 reputation all your tag edits are revised by some one with more reputation, namely someone with [more than 2000](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit).

So yes, you have edited tags, yes you have gotten your badge for editing those tags, but only after 500+ reputation you will be able to do it alone ;)

Answer (score 6):

Most editing privileges mean editing without approval.  You can submit an edit before that, but it has to go through the review page.